# How do I increase drop down option character limit in Microsoft Word 2013?

Tags: ms-word

I have a form on Word 13 with text input fields and **Drop-down list content control**. Each option in the drop down list cannot exceed a certain number of characters,is there a way to set the character limit? I  have very long values for the options and they get truncated. Just to add, I simply used the content control properties to add the options.

I'm not using any coding or so yet.

Please advice on how can I increase drop down option character limit or set it to unlimited chars?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are "the options"? Is this from your code, or when you're just using Excel? If it's in code, how are you displaying those options? We cannot read your mind or see your screen from where we are sitting. If you want us to help you, you need to **be specific** about what you're asking. This question is like "How can I make my program faster?" when we have no idea what your program is or what it does.

Comment: FYI, what I was asking is simply I have a form on Word 13 with text input fields and ** Drop down list content control ** Each option in the drop down list cannot exceed a certain number of characters, so my question is, is there a way to set the character limit? I'm not using any coding or so yet. Just to add, I simply used the content control properties to add the options..Please advice.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you're asking there, instead of in comments. If you bury it in comments, the question remains unclear (which is why I commented in the first place).